# Measures to prevent screen burn

Tags: static, screen, screensaver, lcd

I recently wrote a program to display data on a set of LCD TV's. The data is for the most part static with the exception of refreshing from the database every 60 seconds. I know screen burn isn't as big an issue with LCD's as Plasma TV's, however, I would like to try and minimize the risk. These screens will be running for 8 hours a day.

I programmed a small square that bounces around the screens on top of all the data. The square constantly changes colors as it goes. I did test that it hits every pixel on the screen. It completes a "cycle" every couple of minutes.

Is that sufficient to mitigate the risk of burn in? Or do I need to make something more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Discard all the effort altogether, LCDs do not sufer from that problem at all.

And that square is probalby annoying, and even if it were to do any good, it would have to stay on the screen for longer period of time.

And - I wouldn't worry, 8 hours per day is normal. If you are paranod, you can move the window / re-place the text every so.

Answer (score 0):

That is not true exactly. While LCD don't suffer from what burn in actually is. They do have a similar problem, especially when used as a computer screen, or left on a tv guide. An image will stick if left on the screen long enough, usually goes away but it can be permanent.

The program you are describing sounds like it would work just fine.